# Home directory being symlinked all over

Tags: home-directory, symbolic-link

first post in this community. I am using Ubuntu 20.10 installed on WSL 2 and I have not had any issues after upgrading until recently. I noticed that my home directory is being symlinked all over the place in random directories as `'~'` and I can't figure out what is causing this. I can remove those references with `rm -rf '~'` but it pops back up shortly after.

Have any of you seen something like this before? I am not even really sure how to dig into what is causing this to be linked everywhere. And by everywhere, I mean like anywhere I visit in the terminal seems to get a nice little symlink back to the home directory.

EDIT: Using `l '~'` to get more info I get this
[image: more info on directory]

Comment: No cause I am not creating those directories. I understand what the tilde means, but I don't know why `'~'` keeps popping up everywhere as I am not creating it.

Comment: The distinction is that the directory is a named `'~'` the single quotes around it are the important difference there. I changed into the directory and went into the config directory there and I am seeing `.config/nvim/undodir/` so I think my neovim plugin is doing something strange here

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is an errant setting in my `init.lua` file for neovim. I am setting the undodir to `~/.config/nvim/undodir` and somehow it is interpreting that as a local path instead of the actual home directory path to my nvim config. I will have to look into this further as to why that is happening, but it explains why the directory is just popping up.

Whenever I undo something in Neovim, it is creating an undo file at `./'~'/.config/nvim/undodir` which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: ... so it was an ordinary directory - not a symbolic link at all?

Comment: yes it appears so >.< I mistook it for a symlink. Apologies on the confusion

Answer (score 0):

the correct undodir configuration if you are using `init.lua` is:

```lua
vim.o.undodir = os.getenv("HOME") .. '/.vim/undo'
```